# Noob with a syntax error in dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error, emoji

I am trying to learn Python following the tutorial from Programming with Mosh.

I have created a program that starts up and greets me and then asks me to select an item on a list. Each list item is a "sub-program" that the tutorial covers. So I have two sub-programs in my program:

- A chat translator that should return text and, via a dictionary, convert :) and :( to emojis
- Then also a square calculator.

The problem I am facing is that my chat translator runs into a syntax error in the dictionary. This is where the error happens, at the first quotation mark in line 2 of the dictionary:

```
C:\Users\smelt\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/smelt/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/venv/app.py
  File "C:\Users\smelt\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\app.py", line 41
    ":(": emoji.emojize(":frowning_face:")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Part of the code the error happens in:

```py
def emoji_converter(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    emojis = {
        ":)": emoji.emojize(":smiling_face:"),
        ":(": emoji.emojize(":frowning_face:")
    }
    output = ""
    for word in words:
        output += emojis.get(word, word) + " "
    return output
```

This is my entire code:

```py
first_name = "Henrik"
last_name = "Skaaning"
program_on = True
calculator_on = False
emoji_converter_on = False

def greet_user(first_name, last_name):
    # Standard greeting to user
        print(f"""Hi {first_name} {last_name}!
Welcome back!
""")

if program_on:
    while program_on:
        greet_user(first_name, last_name)
        selection = input(f"""This is Training program for Henrik Skaaning.
please enter a number to select a program to run
    1: Emoji converter
    2: Square calculator
enter "quit" to quit program...
selection> """)

        if selection == "1":
            emoji_converter_on = True
            print(f'Emoji converter on')

            while emoji_converter_on:
                import emoji

                def emoji_converter(message):
                    words = message.split(" ")
                    emojis = {
                        ":)": emoji.emojize(":smiling_face:"),
                        ":(": emoji.emojize(":frowning_face:")
                    }
                    output = ""
                    for word in words:
                        output += emojis.get(word, word) + " "
                    return output


                message = input("message> ")
                if message != "help":
                    if message != "quit":
                        print(emoji_converter(message))

                if message == "help":
                    print(f"""This is a simple emoji converter developed by Henrik Skaaning. 
Type a text in the command line with an emoji to return the text and emoji.
Type "help" in the command line to return the help-menu.  
Type "quit" in the command line to quit the application. """)

                if message == "quit":
                    emoji_converter_on = False
                    print(f'Emoji converter shutting off')

        if selection == "2":
            calculator_on = True
            print(f'Square calculator on')

        while calculator_on:

            def square(number):
                return int(number) * int(number)


            number = input("commandline> ")
            if number == "quit":
                program_on = False
                calculator_on = False
                print(f'Executing')
            if number != "quit":
                if number != "help":
                    if number.isnumeric() != True:
                        print(f"Sorry! That isnt a command i understand")
            if number == "help":
                print(f"""This is a simple square calculator developed by Henrik Skaaning. 
Type a number in the command line to return the square of that number
Type "help" in the command line to return the help-menu.  
Type "quit" in the command line to quit the application. """)

            if number.isnumeric():
                result = square(number)
                print(f' The result is {result}')

if program_on == False:
    print(f'Program shut down')

print(f'Done...')
```

Comment: Is this code exactly the same as you are running? What version of python are you using? I have just run your code as posted in 3.8 and am not getting any syntax errors.

Comment: I moved the function out of the while-loop as suggested by Mike and added a comma in the dictionary after the first term line - that did the trick. 

my code is now working as i inteded it to!

Comment: Please accept his answer when it fixed your problem.

Comment: already did! i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to define a function within another function, and sometimes using a closure makes things easier, this code has a really long mainline with a function defined within a while loop. This code would be better and easier to understand if it was written with the functions separated. Otherwise, as you now know, it can be hard to debug.

The actual problem is that you have confused the syntax for a Python `dict` and JSON. A `dict` requires symbol / value pairs, while JSON requires string / value pairs.

Below is a reorganized program for you. The bug was not corrected.

```py
first_name = "Henrik"
last_name = "Skaaning"
program_on = True
calculator_on = False
emoji_converter_on = False

def emoji_converter(message):
    words = message.split(" ")
    emojis = {
        ":)": emoji.emojize(":smiling_face:"),
        ":(": emoji.emojize(":frowning_face:")
    }
    output = ""
    for word in words:
        output += emojis.get(word, word) + " "
    return output

def greet_user(first_name, last_name):
    # Standard greeting to user
        print(f"""Hi {first_name} {last_name}!
Welcome back!
""")


if program_on:
    while program_on:
        greet_user(first_name, last_name)
        selection = input(f"""This is Training program for Henrik Skaaning.
please enter a number to select a program to run
    1: Emoji converter
    2: Square calculator
enter "quit" to quit program...
selection> """)

        if selection == "1":
            emoji_converter_on = True
            print(f'Emoji converter on')

            while emoji_converter_on:
                import emoji

                message = input("message> ")
                if message != "help":
                    if message != "quit":
                        print(emoji_converter(message))

                if message == "help":
                    print(f"""This is a simple emoji converter developed by Henrik Skaaning.
Type a text in the command line with an emoji to return the text and emoji.
Type "help" in the command line to return the help-menu.
Type "quit" in the command line to quit the application. """)

                if message == "quit":
                    emoji_converter_on = False
                    print(f'Emoji converter shutting off')

        if selection == "2":
            calculator_on = True
            print(f'Square calculator on')

        while calculator_on:

            def square(number):
                return int(number) * int(number)


            number = input("commandline> ")
            if number == "quit":
                program_on = False
                calculator_on = False
                print(f'Executing')
            if number != "quit":
                if number != "help":
                    if number.isnumeric() != True:
                        print(f"Sorry! That isnt a command i understand")
            if number == "help":
                print(f"""This is a simple square calculator developed by Henrik Skaaning.
Type a number in the command line to return the square of that number
Type "help" in the command line to return the help-menu.
Type "quit" in the command line to quit the application. """)

            if number.isnumeric():
                result = square(number)
                print(f' The result is {result}')

if program_on == False:
    print(f'Program shut down')

print(f'Done...')
```

Now that you know you need a symbol instead of strings like ":)" and ":(", can you fix it yourself?

Hint: use string substitution instead of a `dict`. Convert all `":)"` strings to `":smiling_face:"`, and `":("` strings to `":frowning_face:"`, like:

```py
message.replace(":)", ":smiling_face:").replace(":(", ":frowning_face:")
```

The corrected program should be noticeably shorter.

Comment: Why does OP need symbols? `{":)": emoji.emojize(":foo:")}` is perfectly valid python

Comment: He does not need symbols. I merely told him why the error occurred, then I gave advice on how to greatly simplify `emoji_converter` without symbols.

Comment: But that is not why they are getting errors. The code as posted does not give a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I moved the function out of the while-loop as you suggested, Mike,  and added a comma in the dictionary after the first term line - that did the trick. my code is now working as i intended it to!

Simplifying comes later in my learning curve i think :P

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is not the code you ran to generate that error message. It does not give a syntax error and the line in the error is now on line 33 not 41 as in the stacktrace.

My guess is that you missed the comma after the first dict entry

```py
emojis = {
    ":)": emoji.emojize(":smiling_face:")
    ":(": emoji.emojize(":frowning_face:")
}
```

gives the error you got.